# Connect a MacBook to the company network through VPN of second MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, network, vpn, tunnel

I need to connect a new MacBook Pro to the company network and then log in once to get the account running.

Unfortunately, I live very far away from the company, so it would be great if I could do it remotely.

Also pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> during boot does not work, I still get to the login screen, so this seems no solution.

**My idea:**

I still have the old MacBook with a working VPN connection to the company network. Is it possible to share it somehow?

[ ROUTER - Wlan] -- [Wlan -- [ VPN - Tunnel ] -- OldMB -- en0 ] -- [ en0 -- NewMB ]

**Question:**

What would I need to configure in the old MacBook to route all eth0 packets into the tunnel? We use OpenVPN.

And do I need a special cross cable to connect the two Macs?

Will the routing be enough for the new MacBook to request an IP per DHCP?

Comment: Apple silicon Macs don't use the old startup key commands [though I'm not sure why you feel you need those anyway] To get to the equivalent, you press & hold the power button down at switch on until you see the startup options window. tbh, I think you're going to have to ask your IT department.

Comment: their solution was to drive into the office :) if i can create a local account, that would be acceptable. will try your idea later, thx!!

Comment: This may all depend on how the Mac was originally set up - if there's an MDM on it you may have no choice. If it's just 'out of the box factory default', that's different.

Comment: @Tetsujin the long press on power worked, but the macbook has file vault enabled and a restore password and so on .. can't really do anything in the startup options interface.

Comment: is there maybe a better forum for the vpn sharing topic? it's not really mac specific, more linux-ish?

Comment: Have you tried just enabling sharing from your old Mac's internet connection? If you're in full charge of that one, it should be easy. The only thing you can't do is share to the same 'socket' as you're getting your own net connection from - so you share en0 to wifi etc, not back to en0.

Comment: @Tetsujin .. had to buy a usb-c to ethernet adapter first for the new macbook ... when I go to Settings -> Share -> Internet Connection, I can only share the Wireless Connection or Thunderbolt. I don't see a way, how to share the OpenVPN-Tunnel interface. Any ideas?

Comment: You share your 'route to the internet' to a.n.other 'socket'. So, Ethernet to WiFi or WiFi to Ethernet etc.

Comment: Yeah, but then it will probably use the default nameservers etc from the wireless router. Our company has internal nameservers when you connect via VPN, so the access of the AD-service is only possible if you use the internal nameservers. At least I assume this because I could not login with my credentials after sharing the connection.